# Using HTML in form value

Tags: html, forms

Simple question, however I can't find an answer anywhere.

I need a text input that can display HTML in it's value i.e:

```
<input type="text" name="guest_sc_player" id="guest_sc_player" size="27" value="<iframe width="100%" height="166" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="http://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F34196707&show_artwork=true"></iframe>" />
```

Comment: Why not use the iframe by itself?

Comment: Search Stack Overflow with "html wysiwyg".

Comment: I think you're looking for a textarea, not a text input. You'll need to html-encode your html too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the other answers will work for this specific situation, but the *correct* way to do this is to [HTML Encode](http://www.breakingpar.com/bkp/home.nsf/0/87256B280015193F87256C47007456E7) the entire value:

```
<input type="text" name="guest_sc_player" id="guest_sc_player" size="27" value="&lt;iframe width=&quot;100%&quot; height=&quot;166&quot; scrolling=&quot;no&quot; frameborder=&quot;no&quot; src=&quot;http://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F34196707&amp;show_artwork=true&quot;&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;" />​​​​​​​​
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C3v6B/)

This avoids the necessity of worrying whether there may be single or double quotes in the value string. Depending on what platform you're using, there's probably a convenience method to do this automatically. e.g. [HttpUtility.HtmlEncode in .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.htmlencode.aspx)

Comment: As I was using a PHP string I used htmlentities()

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" name="guest_sc_player" id="guest_sc_player" size="27" value='<iframe width="100%" height="166" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="http://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F34196707&show_artwork=true"></iframe>' />
```

single quotes work too.

Answer (score 0):

Replace those double quotes within the `value` property with `&quot;`.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to encode all the characters that are required to be encoded.

Then, you can surround the string in single quotes.

```
<input type="text" name="guest_sc_player" id="guest_sc_player" size="27" value='&lt;iframe width="100%" height="166" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="http://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F34196707&amp;show_artwork=true"&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;' />
```